# javascript - CategorySelect is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to get a jsfiddle of a multiselect working but I get an error in the console:

> CategorySelect is not a constructor

How is my CategorySelect not a constructor?

code:

```
var CategorySelect = (function() {
    function CategorySelect() {
        var _this = this;
        this._configureMultiselect = function() {
            _this._multiselectConfiguration = {
                buttonWidth: '100%',
                buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
                buttonClass: 'none',
                nonSelectedText: "select category",
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                disableIfEmpty: true,
                onSelectAll: function() {
                    if (!$("#category-div span.multiselect-selected-text").text()) {
                        $("#category-div span.multiselect-selected-text").text('Select category');
                    }
                },
                onChange: function(option, checked) {
                    _this._selectedCategories = ko.observableArray([]);
                    var self = _this;
                    $('#category-select option:selected').each(function() {
                        self._selectedCategories.push(($(this).text(), $(this).val()));
                    });
                    console.log(_this._selectedCategories());
                }
            };
        };
        this._instantiateCategories = function() {
            _this._categories = ko.observableArray([
                new Category("Vegan Meat", 1),
                new Category("Vegan Dairy", 2),
                new Category("Confectionary", 3),
                new Category("Baking", 4),
                new Category("Dessert", 5),
                new Category("Restaurants", 6),
                new Category("Grocers", 7)
            ]);
        };
        this._configureMultiselect();
        this._instantiateCategories();
        $("#category-select").multiselect(this._multiselectConfiguration);
    }
    return CategorySelect;
})();
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/211/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the scope in JavaScript, but never their assignments.

At the time you reference `CategorySelect`, it hasn't been set to anything, it's like there is a `var CategorySelect;` at the top of the containing scope, leading to its value being `undefined`, and hence *not a constructor*.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1k6jce75/).